# Two-part AppleScript key sequence?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to assign a keyboard shortcut to the screenshot app window feature (if you didn't know, it is <kbd>⌘⇧+4</kbd>, then <kbd>Space</kbd>, which allows you to take a screenshot of a single app window).

I have been trying to code it as an AppleScript for almost an hour, but there is something I am missing; I am only getting the standard screenshot selection feature.

The code I have so far is:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 21 using {shift down, command down}
    key code 49
end tell
```

Does anyone know how to code the key sequencing that I am trying to do above? Or have a resource that describes how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Was missing a delay.

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 21 using {shift down, command down}
    delay 0.1
    key code 49
end tell
```

Then assign to a keyboard shortcut using Alfred, Quicksilver or other similar application.

Comment: If anyone has a really good and not too voluminous resource for AppleScript, I am up for learning. Cheers.

Comment: A good place to start is [Introduction to AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) and the following document is handy to have locally on your system, [AppleScript Language Guide (2013) PDF](https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/applescriptlanguageguide-2013.pdf). It you're going to use a language then you should at the least read the Language Guide. ;)